# morphia annotation

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am using mongodb with java and also morphia.

For my usecase i get collection name  at run time. So i have a enum of collection names and based on some value i get the corresponding collection name from enum. My entity annotation is as follows

```
@entity(EnumName.getCollectionName())
```

But i get the following error

```
"The value for annotation attribute Entity.value must be a constant expression"
```

I am actually returning a constant expression only. Could anyone let me know what the issue is.

Comment: Why do you get collection name at run-time? Is that something you could put in a configuration file rather than getting it at run-time?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use some something dynamic within annotations as those are "compile" time features which can't be changed afterwards. So you can only handle constants which you declared there, Enums and Classes. For this a smart compiler may be able to find out that you handle something which may never change, but most wont and will simply error as soon as they see that you're trying asign some function value to an annotation property.

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but it somehow looks like you try to use one "generic" entity class for several concrete entities. I think this is really bad design.
If you can tell more details, we may be able to give you a proper solution for your problem.

If you simply don't know what Class you have to operate with at runtime, try this.
Declare your concrete entities and fill your enum with those Classes. At Runtime you can do `Datastore.find(Enum.YOURCLASS)` and morphia will query your appropriate class.